# Import Error: No Module named common

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

My folder structure in pycharm is as follows.

```
--python
  --concepts
    --common
      --myds.py
      --__init__.py
    --data_structures
      --test_ds.py
```

I have the following line in `test_ds.py`

```
from common import my_ds
```

I get the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'common'
```

I have added `common` to `Settings --> Project Interpreter -> Interpreter Paths`
and the folder shows up as `library root`.

Still why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try `from ..common import my_ds`. Also make sure that it has an `__init__.py` file in that directory (not required but it's good practice).

As for the `..` they indicate that you're importing from the parent package to the one you're currently on.

Comment: I get `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` when is use `..`

Comment: Oh, the parent directory also needs a `__init__.py` file! Even if it's completely empty. If the parent directory was not meant to be a python package you'll need to restructure your packages differently.

Comment: By parent directory you mean in `concepts` folder in tree structure above.

Comment: Yes! The parent to common. But now that I look at your structure you may not be loading the packages, are you running test_ds.py directly? (by that I mean are you doing something like `python python/concepts/data_structures/test_ds.py`) In that case you either need a little "hack" by adding the common folder to sys.path so that python can internally find the modules. Just make sure that there is no package named `common` in your site-packages:

    `import os
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your common folder into a python package in order to import it in python. I think you've tried to do it and created `init` file in your `common` folder but actually it must be `__init__.py`. Rename it like this and then your package will be visible to python.

Hope it helps!